# Конкатенация нескольких строк?

Tags: perl

```
my $var1 = "<?\$s='" . 'x'x4;
```

Есть строка `$var1`. Не могу понять как добавить в конец символ `'`

Comment: `my $var1 = "<?\$s='" . ('x'x4) . "'";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно принципу TMTOWTDI, это можно сделать несколькими способами.

Самый простой:

```
my $var1 = "<?\$s='" . 'x'x4 . "'";
```

Часто удобно использовать join (так же это быстрее работает, особенно если среди собираемых данных есть переменные:

```
my $var1 = join('', "<?\$s='", 'x'x4, "'");
```

Или вообще написать строку без всяких операторов конкатенации (вставкой исполнимого кода в строку, через `@{[]}`):

```
my $var1 = "<?\$s='@{['x'x4]}'";
```

Правда с читабельностью у него не очень. Выбирайте наиболее удобный и понятный для вас.